# Android package duplication Error - Activity null pointer exception

Tags: android, eclipse, package, null-pointer

When i run my error free app, it crashes on runtime. `Null pointer Exception`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.besu.test/com.besu.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is the deal, my package is: "`com.besu.test`" i dont know why eclipse duplicated it when the app launched the Main activity "`com.besu.test.MainActivity`" coz obviously no such directory as "`com.besu.test/com.besu.test.MainActivity`" is found in the project. and yes i did declare the `activity` in the `manifest` with the "`category launcher`" intent.

Appreciate it. cheers.

Comment: It's just your app package and the full class name of the activity that couldn't be started. If you look below in the stacktrace, you see the actual NPE and where it occurs.

Comment: Thanks Laalto, hidden way down in the stack trace is the problem.

Comment: Ok, since there doesn't seem to be a further problem, I've expanded the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentInfo` is a class that contains your app package and a fully qualified class name. No duplication there, it's just that your app package is the same as the package for your activity class.

In this case the `ComponentInfo` is used for identifying an activity to start, and there was an NPE starting the activity. The exception is wrapped in this `RuntimeException` with additional component information to help debugging.

To see the root NPE, look below in the stacktrace for a "caused by" exception and where it occurs in your code.